# java Help clarifying Factory Methods with Generic Classes

Tags: java, generics, static, factory

Honestly, I'm not sure the title fits this correctly; But I will try to explain my problem with examples.

Say I have two classes

```
public class Entity {
    private static int lastID = 0;
    private int ID;

    private Entity(){};

    public static Entity create(){
        lastID++;

        Entity ent = new Entity();
        ent.ID = lastID;

        return ent;
    }
}

public class Blob extends Entity {
    private int x,y;

    pubic void setPos(int X,int Y){;
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
}
```

The way I'd like to interface with the Entity factory would be in the form of

```
Blob b = Entity.create<Blob>();
```

Or something in that nature.

My best attempt was

```
public static <E extends Entity> E create(){
    E ent = new E();
    ...
```

but that doesn't want to work.

Comment: If you have a generic Class like `E` you can not initiate it by `new E()`

Comment: I was hoping E would be an alias for the Blob class

Comment: Why don't you simply use the classic Factory pattern to do what you need? You need to pass some parameter to the factory method that helps determine what instance of Entity to create, however

Comment: The only way I could think of is to pass the desired class as a parameter, create the desired class, then down cast it to return it from the function, and then recast it back. I'm almost positive this would be a bad way to go about it,But is this what you were suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it can't be done without actually passing a class or its name as an argument.

You can then use a generic construction `<E extends Entity<E>>` to make it typesafe and avoid manual type casting.

```
public class Entity<E extends Entity<E>> {
    private static int lastID = 0;
    protected int ID;

    protected Entity() {
    }

    public static <E extends Entity<E>> E create(Class<E> clazz) {
        lastID++;

        E newItem;
        try {
            newItem = clazz.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // let's hope your child classes will have a working default constructor 
        }
        newItem.ID = lastID;
        return newItem;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
}

public class Blob extends Entity<Blob> {
    private int x,y;

    public Blob() {
    }

    public void setPos(int X,int Y){;
        x = X;
        y = Y;
    }
}

public class AnotherBlob extends Entity<AnotherBlob> {

    String help = "Help!";

    public String help() {
        return help;
    }

}

// TEST!
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blob blob = Entity.create(Blob.class);
        AnotherBlob anotherBlob = Entity.create(AnotherBlob.class);

        System.out.println("Blob: " + blob.getClass() + " ID = " + blob.getID() +
                "\nAnother blob: " + anotherBlob.getClass() + " ID = " + anotherBlob.getID());
    }

}
```

Comment: This was more along the lines of what I was looking for. Passing the class is a bummer, but this is the best solution. Thank you very much myfriend.

Comment: Generics in java are compile-time only, so at runtime the JVM won't be able to determine what class to instantiate. That's why the parameter is required.

Comment: You can remove `<E extends Entity<E>>` from class declaration, and make a static method `<E extends Entity>`. The test in my answer above will still work, but the compiler will allow you to make Blob b = Entity.create(ChildOfBlob.class). If that's ok, you can reduce the generic clutter. The suggestion in my answer won't allow you to instantiate children on Blobs.

Comment: Oh Thank you very much I forgot to mention how helpful this was, it greatly reduced clutter from all the  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")

Answer (score 1):

A simple factory method might look something like this. Keep it in its own class (not in Entity class) and have the name **Factory** someplace in name so it has context

```
public static final Entity getInstance(String id){
    Entity instance = null;
    if(id.equals("Blob")) {
        instance = new Blob();
    }
    else if(id.equals("Another Blob")) {
        instance = new AnotherBlob();
    }
    // more Entity types here
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Or you can pass an class and check `instanceof`, like `getInstance(Class<?> cls)`

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid hard-coded generation of the class however. It just doesn't seem like a very scale able approach.

Comment: The purpose of the Factory method is to create an instance of Entity that is not known at compile time..If you don't like the approach I have given, you can also use java.lang.Class.forName(String className) as another way of making it more generic passing a Class parameter or something along those lines (getting the classname directly from Class parameter)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification regarding the proper use of factory methods.